# Cannot see reports in SQL Nexus

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-administration

I installed SQL Nexus utiltity, but I cannot see the reports on left handside.  I see the following:

[image]

How do get Nexus to install and see the following:

[image]

I followed the direction and install the RML utiltites also.  What am I doing wrong?

thank
np

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new version of sql nexus (4.xxx) looks and works differently than older versions. Just click on the "SQL Perf Main" and you will see all the new report options that are possible to use on the main screen.

Comment: Hi, after opening the SQL Perf Main I can't open any report. Some of them are available but clicking on the link doesn't do anything. Any ideia?

Answer (score 0):

After you open SQL Perf Main, you get a report with blue clickable links.

However if they aren't clickable (as you've reported) then you need [Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 Report Viewer (KB2549864)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27231).

The pre-reqs on [the site page](https://sqlnexus.codeplex.com/) were updated to mention this.

Answer (score -1):

Extract the zip files into the DataCollectors folder. This should allow you to view the reports.

This worked for me with version 4.0.0.64.